# How to create a new column based on the mode of some other columns in a data frame in R

Tags: r, dplyr, mode

I have a data frame like this:

| id | w1 | w2 | w3 | w4 | w5 | w6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11 | light | light | light | light | light | light |
| 22 | light | light | light | light | medium | medium |
| 33 | light | light | medium | medium | medium | heavy |
| 44 | light | light | medium | NA | NA | NA |
| 55 | light | light | medium | medium | NA | NA |
| 66 | medium | medium | medium | NA | NA | NA |

I would like to get the frequency count of light, medium, heavy for each id across w1-w6. And I would to get the mode of w1-w6 as a new column.

The target df should look like this:

| id | w1 | w2 | w3 | w4 | w5 | w6 | N_light | N_medium | N_heavy | final |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11 | light | light | light | light | light | light | 6 | 0 | 0 | light |
| 22 | light | light | light | light | medium | medium | 4 | 2 | 0 | light |
| 33 | light | light | medium | medium | medium | heavy | 2 | 3 | 1 | medium |
| 44 | light | light | medium | NA | NA | NA | 2 | 1 | 0 | light |
| 55 | light | light | medium | medium | NA | NA | 2 | 2 | 0 | light |
| 66 | medium | medium | medium | NA | NA | NA | 0 | 3 | 0 | medium |

The real data frame has millions of rows. I struggle to find an efficient way to do this. Any ideas?

I tried the Mode function from DescTools library, that worked with a limited number of rows in a for loop. But it is too slow to run.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you please read and incorporate elements from [How to make a great R reproducible example?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/1082435). Especially the aspects of using `dput()` for the input and then an explicit example of your expected dataset?

Comment: Is the [modeest](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=modeest) package any faster?

Comment: As a rule, loops are slower than say, apply (or using functions in the purrr library). Another option is `dtplyr`: https://www.business-science.io/code-tools/2019/08/15/big-data-dtplyr.html

Comment: I've added a solution for how to get the mode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this asks for `dplyr`, but if other find base R useful you could simply index and use `*apply` functions

```
xx <- unique(unlist(df[-1]))
xx <- xx[!is.na(xx)]
 # or xx <- c("light", "medium", "heavy")
newnames <- paste0("N_",xx)

df[newnames] <- sapply(xx, 
                       function(x) rowSums(df[,-1] == x, 
                                           na.rm = TRUE))
df["final"] <- xx[apply(df[newnames], 1, which.max)]
```

Output:

```
  id     w1     w2     w3     w4     w5     w6 N_light N_medium N_heavy  final
1 11  light  light  light  light  light  light       6        0       0  light
2 22  light  light  light  light medium medium       4        2       0  light
3 33  light  light medium medium medium  heavy       2        3       1 medium
4 44  light  light medium   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>       2        1       0  light
5 55  light  light medium medium   <NA>   <NA>       2        2       0  light
6 66 medium medium medium   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>       0        3       0 medium
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a `tidyverse` solution:

```
df %>%
  #cast all columns except `id` longer:
  pivot_longer(-id) %>%
  # for each combination of ...
  group_by(id, value) %>%
  # ... count the frequencies of distinct values:
  summarise(N = ifelse(is.na(value), NA, n())) %>%
  # omit rows with `NA`:
  na.omit() %>% 
  # remove duplicated rows:
  slice_head() %>% 
  # for each `id`...
  group_by(id) %>%
  # ... cast back wider:
  pivot_wider(names_from = value, values_from = N,
              names_prefix = "N_") %>% 
  # replace `NA` with 0:
  mutate(across(starts_with("N"), ~replace_na(., 0))) %>%
  # bind result back to original `df`:
  bind_cols(df%>% select(-id), .) %>%
  # reorder columns:
  select(id, everything())
  id     w1     w2     w3     w4 N_light N_medium N_heavy
1  1  light  light  light  light       4        0       0
2  2  light  light  light  light       4        0       0
3  3  light  light medium medium       2        2       0
4  4  light  light   <NA> medium       2        1       0
5  5  light  light medium medium       2        2       0
6  6 medium medium   <NA>  heavy       0        2       1
```

**EDIT**:

If the ultimate goal is to compute the mode for the three new columns, then this may be a way to go:

```
# First define a function for the mode:

getmode <- function(v) {
  uniqv <- unique(v[!is.na(v)])
  uniqv[which.max(table(match(v, uniqv)))]
}

# Second, do as before:

df %>%
  #cast all columns except `id` longer:
  pivot_longer(-id) %>%
  # for each combination of ...
  group_by(id, value) %>%
  # ... count the frequencies of distinct values:
  summarise(N = ifelse(is.na(value), NA, n())) %>%
  # omit rows with `NA`:
  na.omit() %>% 
  # remove duplicated rows:
  slice_head() %>% 
  # for each `id`...
  group_by(id) %>%
  # ... cast back wider:
  pivot_wider(names_from = value, values_from = N,
              names_prefix = "N_") %>% 
  # replace `NA`with 0:
  mutate(across(starts_with("N"), ~replace_na(., 0))) %>%
  # bind result back to original `df`:
  bind_cols(df%>% select(-id), .) %>%
  select(id, everything()) %>%

  # Third, add to this the computation of the mode:
  
  # compute mode:
  summarise(across(starts_with("N"), ~getmode(.)))
  N_light N_medium N_heavy
1       2        2       0
```

Data:

```
df <- structure(list(id = 1:6, w1 = c("light", "light", "light", "light", 
                                      "light", "medium"), w2 = c("light", "light", "light", "light", 
                                                                 "light", "medium"), w3 = c("light", "light", "medium", NA, "medium", 
                                                                                            NA), w4 = c("light", "light", "medium", "medium", "medium", "heavy"
                                                                                            )), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Answer (score 0):

in Base R you could do:

```
a <- table(cbind(dat[1], stack(dat, -1))[1:2])
cbind(dat, as.data.frame.matrix(a), final = colnames(a)[max.col(a)])

   id     w1     w2     w3     w4     w5     w6 heavy light medium  final
11 11  light  light  light  light  light  light     0     6      0  light
22 22  light  light  light  light medium medium     0     4      2  light
33 33  light  light medium medium medium  heavy     1     2      3 medium
44 44  light  light medium   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>     0     2      1  light
55 55  light  light medium medium   <NA>   <NA>     0     2      2 medium
66 66 medium medium medium   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>     0     0      3 medium
```